# How to get existing users using Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Once Timeline goes live, how do we get our users to give `publish_actions` permission?

We've added this to our Auth Dialog settings, should we redirect (existing-)users back to that dialog once timeline goes live to get `publish_actions` permission, or will that happen automatically?

Also, it seems the auth dialog happens automatically now, without any custom FB code required, if they don't have the app allowed.